# How to solve limit in select query problem?

Tags: mysql

SQL code:

```
select
    car_id, user_id 
from
    orders o
left join
    users u on u.id =  o.user_id
where
    o.user_id in (select id from users limit 3)
```

Mysql Says `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery`

Comment: Please provide relevant sample data and expected output accordingly.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Limiting without ordering makes little sense, apart from producing "random rows". Do you want random rows?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @PauloCastilho there is no `TOP` in MySQL

Comment: i use mysql 5.7

Comment: @АлексейЯгодаров Could you provide some sample data and expect  result?

Comment: @TheImpaler Why do you think the version matters? AFAIK, it's not supported in *any* version.